# Failed to build package

Tags: package-management, deb

I run into a problem trying to build a package.
Everything is OK except adding icon - I added this to `rules` file

```
mkdir -p debian/fbmessenger/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps
cp debian/fbmessenger-facebook.png debian/fbmessenger/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/
```

And while compiling it gives this annoying error:

```
mkdir -p debian/fbmessenger/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps
cp debian/fbmessenger-facebook.png debian/fbmessenger/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/
cp: cannot stat `debian/fbmessenger-facebook.png': No such file or directory
```

It fails to copy icon from debian/ directory but the icon is actually here.
Any hints how to resolve this error will be great.
Cheers, Fih

Comment: Have tried using absolute paths? What is your directory structure for this project?

Comment: this will be later uploaded to Launchpad PPA so absolute patches will not work anyway. but its runed from: ~/Launchpad/fbmessengerrepo/fbmessenger-0.1.0

Comment: Well try adding a debug command like `ls > somfile` to see relative to what the building is occurring.

Comment: funny thing is that if I compile it with `bzr builddeb -- -nc -us -uc` it gives error but with `debuild -us -uc` everythings goes smothly but Launchpad fail at build it anyway

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there is already an icon with the source code and I slightly modified `rules` file to make use of this icon instead of my own one.
Moreover `debuild -us -uc` seem to build that package without problems.